# Scalatra SwaggerSupport NPEs on simple case class?

Tags: scala, scalatra

I'm following the Scalatra Swagger Guide (http://scalatra.org//guides/2.6/swagger.html) but can't get the same results in my own code.  Somehow the SwaggerSupport can't deal with my case class.

```
import org.scalatra._
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}
import org.scalatra.json.NativeJsonSupport
import org.scalatra.swagger.{Swagger, SwaggerSupport}

class SproutServlet(implicit val swagger: Swagger)
  extends ScalatraServlet with NativeJsonSupport with SwaggerSupport {
  ...
  case class Hello(id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString, hello: String = "hello")

  val hello = (apiOperation[Hello] ("hello")
      summary "Hello"
      description "Description for hello")

  get("/hello",operation(hello)) {
    Hello()
  }
}
```

It throws a NullPointerException right where I do the `apiOperation[Hello]` . If I substitute in, say `String` rather than my case class, `Hello`, it works (no stacktrace).  How do I get that apiOperation expression to accept my case class?

Full stacktrace:

```
2019-04-14 21:28:50.995:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@629f0666{/,file:///Users/robert.kuhar/dev/sprout/target/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///Users/robert.kuhar/dev/sprout/target/webapp/}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.$anonfun$findScalaSig$1(ScalaSigReader.scala:133)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:306)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.findScalaSig(ScalaSigReader.scala:133)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.$anonfun$findScalaSig$1(ScalaSigReader.scala:133)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:306)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.findScalaSig(ScalaSigReader.scala:133)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.findClass(ScalaSigReader.scala:41)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.read$1(ScalaSigReader.scala:35)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.$anonfun$readField$1(ScalaSigReader.scala:35)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.read$1(ScalaSigReader.scala:35)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.readField(ScalaSigReader.scala:37)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.Reflector$.$anonfun$createDescriptor$3(Reflector.scala:92)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.Reflector$.fields$1(Reflector.scala:90)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.Reflector$.properties$1(Reflector.scala:105)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.Reflector$.createDescriptor(Reflector.scala:159)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.Reflector$.$anonfun$describe$2(Reflector.scala:44)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.package$Memo.apply(package.scala:16)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.reflect.Reflector$.describe(Reflector.scala:44)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.Swagger$.modelToSwagger(Swagger.scala:110)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.Swagger$.$anonfun$collectModels$8(Swagger.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$flatMap$2(TraversableLike.scala:773)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set2.foreach(Set.scala:132)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.Swagger$.collectModels(Swagger.scala:76)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.Swagger$.collectModels(Swagger.scala:52)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.SwaggerSupportSyntax.registerModel(SwaggerSupport.scala:388)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.SwaggerSupportSyntax.registerModel$(SwaggerSupport.scala:387)
    at com.climate.sprout.SproutServlet.registerModel(SproutServlet.scala:11)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.SwaggerSupport.apiOperation(SwaggerSupport.scala:505)
    at org.scalatra.swagger.SwaggerSupport.apiOperation$(SwaggerSupport.scala:504)
    at com.climate.sprout.SproutServlet.apiOperation(SproutServlet.scala:11)
    at com.climate.sprout.SproutServlet.<init>(SproutServlet.scala:40)
    at ScalatraBootstrap.init(ScalatraBootstrap.scala:14)
    at org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener.configureCycleClass(ScalatraListener.scala:66)
    at org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener.contextInitialized(ScalatraListener.scala:22)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:571)
```

Comment: Sigh.  This is the same stacktrace as a long-standing issue in Scalatra (https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/issues/343).  The conditions aren't the same, there are no Enumerations in my case class.  My faith in the stack has plummeted, though.  I gave my weekend to Scalatra and all I got was this lousy NPE.

Comment: This has got something to do with `implicit lazy val formats = DefaultFormats ++ org.json4s.ext.JavaTypesSerializers.all`.  Deeper in my stack, that succeeds in taking a JSON String and pulling it into a case class off UUID.